# running mapreduce from hdfs

Tags: java, hdfs

When I try to run my program from hdfs using this command:

```
hadoop jar /home/master/Desktop/serveurSo.jar TraitServeur /LogInput6 /output
```

This error of jobconf is shown up:

[image]

This is my program, I put it as an image, I couldn't put it as a code:

[image]

[image]

Where is issue in my jobconf?

Comment: Hello, please include your images directly inside your message

Comment: i can't do it it's the rule of stackoverflow i think !

Comment: Well it is not about posting images, but in your case, you should post your code. Why do you said you could not do it? Just copy/paste your code, and indent 4 spaces, and it will show properly.